# Unity3d load sprite from Textures folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, unityscript

I have around 200 sprites (jpg pictures) in `Assets>Textures>Pictures`, and I have `GameObject` with `<SpriteRenderer>`. Is there a way for me to load sprites from that folder into this `GameObject` in code?
Something like `Resources.Load<Sprite>("path");`

Thank you.

Comment: I have this type of error CS1061: Type `Image' does not contain a definition for `sprite' and no extension method `sprite' of type `Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your folder inside the Resources folder. Like this: `Assets/Textures/Resources/`

Then you can do this:

```
private Object[] textures;

void Awake()
{
    textures = Resources.LoadAll("Path");
}
```

You have to store them as `Objects`. However, if you want to use them later you can do something like this.

```
texture = textures[i] as Texture;
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, the solution **is** `Resources.Load<Sprite>("path")` for a single sprite or `Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("path")` if you want to load them all at once.

In order to use these methods you need to move your sprites into a sub directory named "Resources", e.g, `Assets/Textures/Pictures/Resources`.

This and more information about the consequences of going this way are explained in more detail in the [scripting reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html):

> All assets that are in a folder named "Resources" anywhere in the Assets folder can be accessed via the Resources.Load functions. Multiple "Resources" folders may exist and when loading objects each will be examined.
>
> In Unity you usually don't use path names to access assets, instead you expose a reference to an asset by declaring a member-variable, and then assign it in the inspector. When using this technique Unity can automatically calculate which assets are used when building a player. This radically minimizes the size of your players to the assets that you actually use in the built game. When you place assets in "Resources" folders this can not be done, thus all assets in the "Resources" folders will be included in a build.

Answer (score 0):

Place `awesome.png` in `Assets/Resources/` (you can have subfolders), and use:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = 
    Resources.Load<Sprite>("awesome");  // No file extension.
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html

There's also [LoadAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html) that *"Loads all assets in a folder or file at path in a Resources folder."*